# Flutter - How to get and store the width of an adjustable flat button

Tags: flutter

I need to get and store the width of a standard flat button once it is created, how can I do it?

```
double _width; //store here the flatbutton's width created below

Widget _flatButtonStoreWidth (String text){

  return FlatButton(
    child: Text(text),
    onPressed: () {},
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `LayoutBuilder` widget, here is a demo from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558369/4465386.

```
return FlatButton(
  child: new LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      setState(() => _width = constraints.maxWidth);
        return new Text('this is a button');
    }
  ),
);
```

Comment: I don't want to set its width, i want to get its width once flat button is created. Thanks! :)

Comment: I implemented that in a clean project of Flutter to test it, only with a Scaffold and Center Widget, and it thowed this Exception: The following assertion was thrown building LayoutBuilder:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This MyHomePage widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building.