# Scale down all children in widget by a factor based on the parent size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

In Flutter I am implementing "what's new" screens which will show a preview of the real screens in the app.
For that I reuse the screen `Widgets` in the "what's new" flow.
The preview will be shown in a smaller `Container` and not cover the whole screen.

I want to **scale** down the text sizes, line heights, etc. for all widgets within this `Container` to match the smaller bounds.
Is there a way to do this without individually adding a smaller style for every Widget separately?

*e.g. scale down all `fontSizes` by 20% for a `Widget child` regardless of the size set in the theme*

Comment: I usually use MediaQuery to scale down fonts depending on the screen size tho, not  the child's parent, and found this may be related to your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558368/how-can-i-layout-widgets-based-on-the-size-of-the-parent

Comment: Thanks, it is a working solution but can not be applied to my case because all fonts are defined by a fixed size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Wrapping the child widget tree with `Transform.scale(...)` will scale all the Widgets down the tree according to the supplied scale factor.

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Transform.scale(
      scale: 0.9,
      child: MyScaledWidgetTree(),
     ),
     Container(
      child: ...,
     ),
   ],
)
```

Comment: How do we make the scale dynamic so that it only scales down when there is an overflow? Also, the scale-down value should just be enough to fix the overflow. ie. be as big as it can without any overflow. How do we find that value?