# How to get the height of parent layout - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the height of container

```
 Container( // how to get height of the container
    child: Text('hello,\nhow to get\nheight of the parent layout'),
 ),
```

I try this,

```
  return LayoutBuilder(
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      print(constraints.maxHeight);
      return Container( // how to get height of the container
        child: Text('hello,\nhow to get\nheight of the parent layout'),
      );
    },
  );
```

The height print always 0 value

Comment: max height return 540

Comment: not max height, i want the dynamic height @JahidulIslam

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/41558368/10157127

Answer (score 1):

it will be worked for dynamic height, You need to bind your child with a parent widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              print(constraints.maxHeight);
              return Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight, //set height of the container
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text('hello,\nhow to get\nheight of the parent layout'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About Your code snippet

```
return LayoutBuilder(
    builder:
        (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      print(constraints.maxHeight);
      return Container( // how to get height of the container
        child: Text('hello,\nhow to get\nheight of the parent layout'),
      );
    },
  );
```

You are trying to get child size. To get parent size, you need to use `LayoutBuidler` as child on that widget.

like this,

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, bodyConstraints) {
        print("body height : ${bodyConstraints.maxHeight}");

        return Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, containerConstraints) {
              print("Container height ${containerConstraints.maxHeight}");

              return Text(
                " body Height: ${bodyConstraints.maxHeight} \n container height: ${containerConstraints.maxHeight}",
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

does it solve your issue?

Comment: Container height Infinity. Not working.

Comment: I think it is coming from parent, can you edit the question including its parent and adding context widget tree?

Comment: If it's row/column/expanded......... you might always get infinite height. And yes you are getting height, and it is infinite.

Comment: its column.....

Comment: You will get infinite height in this case as I mentioned in previous comment, I would prefer using Body LayoutBuilder's constraints  and set its children height.

Comment: Do you get the problem now? Feel free to close the question.