# Flutter Web - Display "+X" button when Row should overflow

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

[image]

How can I detect if a Row will overflow, to hide the overflowing elements and replace them with a single button "+X" to indicate how many elements have been hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of the screen by using

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

then do the math (divide the widget by the size width then get rounded down. Using below the [Truncating Division operator](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/num/operator_truncate_divide.html))

```
<Widget Width> ~/ MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

to find out how many components fit in and check how many will be left out of screen.

For example:

If my Widget width is **20** and my screen (or Parent Widget) width is **110**, the above operation will result in **5**

which means 5 elements will be rendered and the others should be factored in your "+ button"

If you want to know your Parent Widget Width and it is variable, check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558369/5666202

Comment: How do you do that if the children can have different sizes ?

Comment: @MockingBird you should have a way of calculating that widget, for example a container width should be set as per example “number of characters * X” and then add that number to some variable that you can access

Comment: @MockingBird did that solve your problem?

Comment: I've found a package name RowOverflowCount (or something like that) and after some fixes (didn't work for some reason), it does exactly what I was looking for.
But yeah, internally it does exactly what you said, it takes a LayoutBuilder and from that it calculates how many elements it can fit in accounting for the inherent length of the element (given its words).